# Where is the error in my email activation function?

Tags: php

I am beginner, I am having small error in my email activation function. the error is in the line of the for loop.

```
<?php
function generateCode(){
$codelength = 20; 
// The length of the activation code.
$characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; // All accepted characters.
$activatecode = "";
for($i=0;$i&lt;=$codelength;$i++){
$activatecode .= substr(str_shuffle($characters),0,1);
}
return $activatecode;
}
$userActivationCode = generateCode();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your less than symbol is html encoded.

```
for($i=0;$i&lt;=$codelength;$i++){
```

change to

```
for($i=0;$i<=$codelength;$i++){
```

Answer (score 3):

Some of your source code is HTML encoded. Perhaps you've copy/pasted it from a website.

On the line with the `for` loop, change `&lt;` to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i&lt
```

is not a valid conditional

you probably mean:

```
for($i=0;$i<=$codelength;$i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function generateCode(){
$codelength = 20; 
// The length of the activation code.
$characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890"; // All accepted characters.
$activatecode = "";
for($i=0;<=$codelength;$i++){
$activatecode .= substr(str_shuffle($characters),0,1);
}
return $activatecode;
}
$userActivationCode = generateCode();
?>
```